# Laplacian and DiracDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, generalized-function

It is known that:

$\nabla^2 \dfrac{1}{|r-r'|} = - 4 \pi \delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$.

If I do that with Mathematica, I find:

```
Laplacian[1/Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2], {x, y, z}];
FullSimplify@%
(*0*)
```

And the same with spherical coordinates.

What do I miss?

Comment: The formula above shows the Gradient, not the Laplacian. As I never heard of the formula, could you please clarify it. It is obvious though that the right hand side needs to be adjusted if instead of the nabla (gradient) operator the Laplacian should appear, because the right hand side obviously is a 3D vector right now.

Comment: In my experience,mma never takes `DiracDelta` as a result except  a few cases input does contains `DiracDelta` or  `FourierTransform[]` e.g.`FourierTransform[1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], t, w]`. : )

Comment: The documentation for `DiracDelta` says that "Only `HeavisideTheta` gives `DiracDelta` after differentiation"...

Comment: Use something like `FullSimplify@Laplacian[ 1/Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2 + eps^2], {x, y, z}]`, and then use the standard representation of the delta - function as a limit `eps -> 0`. Mathematica won't do that limit for you in the sense of distributions.

Comment: The result is zero because *Mathematica* produces results that are *generically* true if you don't add any assumptions. For almost all $\vec{r}$, the result is correct.

Comment: Mathematica will not go in to the land of generalized functions unless something in the input expression triggers its generalized function heuristics.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin but this does not work right? `FullSimplify@ Laplacian[1/Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2 + \[Epsilon]^2], {x, y,  z}]; Limit[%, \[Epsilon] -> 0]`

Comment: @chris It doesn't, automatically (and I noted that), but the result of `FullSimplify` can be easily compared to one of the standard regularizations of Dirac delta functions, for finite `\[Epsilon]`. Jens was able to get Mathematica to actually produce a fully automatic answer by using a  different regularization for the delta-function, and using that Fourier transform is better integrated with Dirac delta functions in Mathematica.

Comment: @Wizard I am sorry I forgot a `^2` in the formula, now it is correct.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin One would like to have a `FullSimplifyWhileBeingCarefull` function or a `TakeLimitWisely` :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update a working approach using Fourier transforms**

The following method is based on the idea that the Laplace operator is just a multiplication with $-k^2$ in **Fourier** space. Therefore, I first find the Fourier transform of the $1/r$ potential and then do an inverse Fourier transform of that result, multiplied by $-k^2$ (which I call `laplacianFT` in the code).

This still requires taking a limit at the right place, because the Fourier transform of the $1/r$ potential in 3D needs to be done by starting with a regularized version. I choose the Yukawa potential with a parameter $\epsilon$. Since *Mathematica* doesn't know how to Fourier transform that function in 3D, I do it by hand as an integral in spherical coordinates. The result is called `ft`.

With that, the rest is easy:

```
laplacianFT = 
 Simplify[Laplacian[E^(I {kx, ky, kz}. {x, y, z}), {x, y, z}]]/
 E^(I {kx, ky, kz}. {x, y, z})

(* ==> -kx^2 - ky^2 - kz^2 *)

ft = Limit[
  Assuming[{kx, ky, kz} ∈ Reals, 
   1/(2 Pi)^(3/2)
     Integrate[
     E^(-ϵ r)/r E^(-I Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2] r Cos[θ])
       r^2 Sin[θ], 
      {r, 0, Infinity}, 
      {θ, 0, Pi}, 
      {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]
   ],
  ϵ -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]

(* ==> Sqrt[2/Pi]/(kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2) *)

InverseFourierTransform[
 laplacianFT ft, {kx, ky, kz}, {x, y, z}]

(* ==> -4 Pi DiracDelta[x] DiracDelta[y] DiracDelta[z] *)
```

This is exactly the desired result. I just set the singularity $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to be at the origin.

**Other possible approaches:**

To get the Dirac Delta function to appear, you could take absolute values in the starting expression on the left-hand side more seriously:

$$\nabla^2 \frac{1}{\vert \vec{r}'-\vec{r}\vert}$$

To do this, define the derivative of the absolute value so that it gives you the Heaviside step function, and do the Laplacian:

```
Abs'[x_] := 2 (HeavisideTheta[x] - 1/2)

FullSimplify[
 Laplacian[
  1/Sqrt[Abs[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2]], {x, y, 
   z}], (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2 >= 0]
```

[image: out]

This is still not an ideal result, but it seems to be valid if you remove the squares from the arguments of the delta functions (using the chain rule), and combine the three terms involving the delta function. There is one other term without a delta function, and one would have to prove that it makes no contribution when integrating any test function across that point. This would then be OK because delta functions are not defined unambiguously. They are distributions, and can differ at isolated points. However, I can't get *Mathematica* to drop that term.

Here is another attempt to get the result in reverse:

```
DSolve[
 Laplacian[f[r], {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"] == -(1/(4 Pi)) DiracDelta[r], f[r], r]

(* ==> {{f[r] -> -(C[1]/r) + C[2]}} *)
```

This is the spherical-coordinate version of the equation. However, *Mathematica* doesn't determine the constant `C[1]` in this approach, so it proves that the equation you're giving is consistent with what *Mathematica* knows, but doesn't quite prove the complete statement.

Comment: +1. It looks like in any case, the best approach currently is to use some regularization and then take the limit.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, I think so, too. The idea to define `Abs'` as `HeavisideTheta` does work in other contexts for me, e.g. when proving Green function identities. But it didn't quite give the desired result in this case.

Comment: ft = ... yields a syntax error "Integrate[ cannot be followed by..."

Comment: bringing the Integrate[...] onto one line resolves the syntax error but the result is "Indeterminate".

Comment: @JamesBowery Indeed, version 13.0 is more picky about the direction of the limit, which is probably a good thing. So I added that information, and it should  work now.