# Teaching Mathematica more about DiracDelta and KroneckerDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

As the documentation and some experimentation indicates, *Mathematica* contains little information about representations of the `DiracDelta` and `KroneckerDelta` functions.

Some examples which are not recognized in *Mathematica* include the identities:

1. `Limit[a/(x^2 + a^2), a -> 0] = DiracDelta[x]`
2. `Integrate[Exp[I k x], {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> k ∈ Reals]`
3. `Sum[Exp[I k n], {n, -∞, ∞}] = KroneckerDelta[k]`
4. `Integrate[h[n, x] h[m, x], {x, -∞, ∞}] = KroneckerDelta[n, m]`
5. `Sum[h[n, x] h[n, y], {n, 0, ∞}] = DiracDelta[x - y]`

Where the set of functions `h[n, x]` is orthonormal.

I want to implement these kinds of relations in *Mathematica*. What would be the programmatic way to do this?

Comment: You may be interested in Leonid's answer to this old question on SO: [How to implement an integration rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7553975)

Comment: For numbers 1 and 2, you can use Fourier transforms instead of integrals, and the result comes out correctly. Specifically, for 1: `InverseFourierTransform[
Limit[
FourierTransform[a/(x^2+a^2),x,y],
a->0],
y,x]` yields $\pi \delta(x)$. See [Laplacian and DiracDelta](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85317/245). This also works with additional relations, not in your list, e.g., `InverseFourierTransform[
Limit[
FourierTransform[Sin[ω t]^2/(π t ω^2),ω,τ],
t->∞],
τ,ω]`

Comment: The outcomes containing `KroneckerDelta` can't be valid in general because *Mathematica* doesn't know that the arguments in those results are supposed to be integers. It generically assumes complex variables, but adds some reality assumptions in `FourierTransform`. So for point 3, you would in general expect something involving `DiracComb` instead of `KroneckerDelta`.

Comment: I want to be able to avoid using FourierTransform because I get these representations (mainly points 4 and 5) automatically in the course of other calculations. I want to be able to use Integrate and assumptions.  How can I extend Integrate using assumptions? Also I need to avoid the results it currently gives which are either infinity or 0.

Answer (score 15):

Since the main goal of the question appears to be dealing with general functions `h` that are assumed to be a complete orthonormal set, I'll deal specifically only with that case.

The idea is to use [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)  as a way of stating the assumptions for the function `h`. To do this, we have to distinguish between the two types of products as they arise in the orthogonality relation (`Integrate`) and the completeness relation (`Sum`). Because the function `h` itself is too deep inside the integral or sum, I define an intermediate function for each of the two types of product first. For them, I then specify what the result of the operation should be.

```
h /: h[n_, x_] h[m_, x_] := hOrthoProduct[n, m, x]
hOrthoProduct /: 
 Integrate[
  hOrthoProduct[n_, m_, x_], {x_, -Infinity, Infinity}] :=  KroneckerDelta[m, n]
h /: h[n_, x_] h[n_, y_] := hCompleteProduct[n, x, y]
hCompleteProduct /: 
 Sum[hCompleteProduct[n_, x_, y_], {n_, 0, Infinity | DirectedInfinity[1]}] := 
 DiracDelta[x - y]
```

Here I test the results:

```
Integrate[h[n, x] h[m, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* ==> KroneckerDelta[m, n] *)

Sum[h[n, x] h[n, y], {n, 0, Infinity}]
(* ==> DiracDelta[x - y] *)
```

**Edit working with built-in functions, in `Limit`, `Sum` or `Integrate`**

As I mentioned in the comments, many known expressions for the delta function can be obtained by wrapping the required limit in Fourier transforms. The point is that the limit (or infinite integration boundary)   can then be interpreted in terms of a generalized function because the intended integration variables are made explicit in `FourierTransform`.

But in `Limit`, `Sum` and `Integrate`, this information is not provided explicitly. So here is a possible way of fixing this lack of information: Whenever we want to perform a limit in the special way that leads to a Dirac delta function, let's just require that in all those cases the **variable** in the limit should have a special name. This name should also include the symbol that's intended to be used as the free integration variable in the conversion to a delta function later.

I decided to call this special variable `ℒ` but give it an *argument* `x` that stands for the free variable. So you will be using variables like `ℒ[x]` or `ℒ[z]` in the calculation. Here are the definitions for this "variable":

```
ℒ /: 
 HoldPattern[
  Rule[ℒ[x_], 
   lim : (0 | Infinity | 
      DirectedInfinity[1])]] := ℒlimit[lim, x]

ℒ /: {ℒ[x_], -Infinity, Infinity} := ℒinterval[x]

ℒlimit /: 
 Limit[expr_, ℒlimit[lim_, x_]] := 
 Module[{y, ϵ},
  InverseFourierTransform[
   Limit[FourierTransform[expr /. ℒ[x] -> ϵ, 
     x, y], ϵ -> lim, Direction -> Sign[lim - 1]], y, x]]

ℒinterval /: 
 op_[expr_, ℒinterval[x_]] := Module[{y, z},
  InverseFourierTransform[
   op[FourierTransform[expr /. ℒ[x] -> z, x, 
     y], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}], y, x]]
```

Now some tests:

```
Limit[ℒ[x]/(x^2 + ℒ[x]^2), ℒ[x] -> 0]

(* ==> Pi DiracDelta[x] *)

Sum[
 Exp[I k ℒ[k]], {ℒ[k], -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* ==> DiracComb[k/(2 Pi)] *)

Integrate[
 Exp[I k ℒ[k]], {ℒ[k], -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* ==> 2 Pi DiracDelta[k] *)

Limit[
 Sin[ω ℒ[ω]]^2/(Pi ℒ[ω] ω^2), ℒ[ω] -> Infinity]

(* ==> DiracDelta[ω] *)
```

So the variable starting with `ℒ` will cause any `Limit`, `Sum` or `Integrate` in which it appears in the second argument to be sandwiched between `InverseFourierTransform` and `FourierTransform` with the additional information about what the desired final variable is.

Comment: That is a very good starting point, thank you!
Could there be a way to do something similar using something like 'Regularization'? (the option for 'Sum' and Product')
How is something like that implemented?

Comment: I don't think so, because you're looking for **generalized functions** as output, and neither `Integrate` nor `Sum` are intended for those kinds of output. Regularizations don't give you generalized functions. The desired delta function output has ambiguities, depending on what is identified as the intended integration variable in the result. In my definitions for `h`, this is made explicit. But in `Integrate` or `Sum`, the first argument is just an expression and there's not enough information to easily identify the intended variables that should appear in `DiracDelta`.