# Write result of integral as Kronecker delta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

Here is some Mathematica code:

```
kroneckerIntegral = Integrate[Sin[m*Pi*x]*Sin[n*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers}]
FullSimplify[kroneckerIntegral, {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers}]
FullSimplify[Integrate[Sin[m*Pi*x]*Sin[m*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}], {m \[Element] Integers}]
```

The resulting Mathematica output of these three lines is:

$$\frac{n \sin (\pi  m) \cos (\pi  n)-m \cos (\pi  m) \sin (\pi  n)}{\pi  m^2-\pi  n^2}$$
$$0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}$$

So essentially `kroneckerIntegral` can be written in terms of a Kronecker delta as $\frac{\delta_{mn} - \delta_{-nm}}{2}$, which is also a direct result of the well known Fourier orthogonality relations.

Now how do I get Mathematica to simplify the integral to that expression? The reason I want to do this is because I have some long calculation that involves a few of these integrals and it would be convenient to tell Mathematica e.g. in form of a rule that I need this expression in terms of the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Actually, the result isn't what you state. It's $\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{m,n}-\delta_{m,-n})$.

Comment: Related: [Teaching Mathematica more about DiracDelta and KroneckerDelta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110263/245)

Comment: @Jens thanks for the linked question and that correction! I completely forgot about those negative numbers ;) I added your result to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: updated with Jens' correct term.

---

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it gets you close? Uses `Inactivate` to do a replace of the integral...

```
term = Inactivate[ Integrate[Sin[m*Pi*x]*Sin[m*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}] ]
kroneckerTerm = term/.term->1/2(KroneckerDelta[m,n]-KroneckerDelta[m,-n])

kroneckerTerm/.{n->2,m->3}

(*  0 *)

kroneckerTerm/.{n->2,m->2}

(*  1/2 *)
```

If you are trying to do a find and replace on some really large expression, you can inactivate the whole thing, do a replace, and `Activate` it. For example...

```
bigterm = Inactivate[
          Integrate[Sin[m*Pi*x]*Sin[m*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}] + 
          Integrate[Sin[m*Pi*x]*Sin[m*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}]^2 + 
          Sin[Integrate[Sin[m*Pi*x]*Sin[m*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}]]
          ];

(bigterm/. term -> 1/2 (KroneckerDelta[m, n] - KroneckerDelta[m, -n]))//Activate

(*  1/2 (-KroneckerDelta[m, -n] + KroneckerDelta[m, n])  
   + 1/4 (-KroneckerDelta[m, -n] + KroneckerDelta[m, n])^2  
   + Sin[1/2 (-KroneckerDelta[m, -n] + KroneckerDelta[m, n])]  *)
```

Comment: +1 awesome stuff, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad to help! Props to @Carl Woll for turning me on to `Inactivate`