# Integrating $ \int\limits_{-\infty }^\infty {{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}}\mathrm d\omega } = 2\pi\, \delta(t) $

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty {{e^{i\omega t}}d\omega} = 2\pi \delta \left( t \right)$ is generally accepted.

But

```
Integrate[E^(I w t), {w, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]
```

gives

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(I t w) does not converge on
>   {-[Infinity],[Infinity]}.

and

```
Integrate[E^(I w t), {w, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]
```

gives `0`

So is it possible to get the correct delta function result?

Comment: Documentation pages of `DiracDelta` say: "Integrate never gives DiracDelta as an integral of smooth functions:... FourierTransform can give DiracDelta", there are appropriate examples, as well.

Comment: @Artes Thank you for this information : )

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110263/teaching-mathematica-more-about-diracdelta-and-kroneckerdelta

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(updated to use [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform) correctly)*

You could use [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform):

```
FourierTransform[1, ω, t, FourierParameters->{1,1}]
```

> ```
> 2 π DiracDelta[t]
> ```

To restrict the integration over the positive $t$ axis, include [`HeavisideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta):

```
FourierTransform[HeavisideTheta[t], t, ω, FourierParameters->{1,1}]
```

> ```
> I/ω + π DiracDelta[ω]
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. +1 What about $\int_0^\infty  {{e^{i\omega t}}dt}  = i{\cal P}\frac{1}{\omega }{\rm{ + }}\pi \delta \left( \omega  \right)$? Is it possible?

Comment: @matheorem See update. I also fixed my usage of FourierTransform.