# How to obtain that result of the integral in Mathematica?

Tags: integral-transforms

I would like to integate this equation:

```
Integrate[Exp[I*(t1-t2)*ω, {ω, -∞, ∞}]
```

According  to a textbook,  I know the answer is $2\pi\delta(t_1 - t_2)$, where $\delta$ is the `DiracDelta` function.   But how can prove this directly in Mathematica?

[image]
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you think your target is true? Can you kindly base it? BTW, the so-called $\delta$-function is not a usual function, but a distribution.

Comment: `FourierTransform[Exp[I (x) w], w, t]`.

Comment: @user64494 can you give a situation where it isn't true? I.e., can you give a function $f(x)$ that does not satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy e^{i x y}f(x)= 2\pi f(0)$? Or maybe a restriction on the set to which $f$ must belong for this to be true?

Comment: Closely related: [Teaching Mathematica more about DiracDelta and KroneckerDelta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110263/245)

Comment: @Roman: Putting $f(x):=1$ , you deal with  a divergent double integral. In general, the notation $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\,dx$ makes no sense in traditional math.

Comment: @user64494 I don't think $f(x)=1$ gives a divergent integral: in polar coordinates, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i x y}dx\,dy=\int_0^{\infty}r\,dr\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \exp(\frac12i r^2 \sin(2\phi))=2\pi\int_0^{\infty}r J_0(r^2/2)dr = \lim_{s\to\infty} \pi s^2 \cdot {_1}F_2(\frac12;1,\frac32;-\frac{r^4}{16})=2\pi$ is quite regular. Sorry for the messed-up markup, I don't know how to do it in this forum.

Comment: @user64494， This eqation is very pupular in quantum physics. You can see the details of this equation in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: @Jens, Roman, march, user64494, Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @Roman: Upgrade your math. You calculate the iterated integral. However, the double integral does not exist. See https://books.google.by/books?id=D_XBAgAAQBAJ for more info.

Comment: @Roman One needs to justify that the double integral is equal to the iterated integral in polar coordinates. If the integral does not diverge, then the order in which the iterated integral is done should not matter, which does not seem to be the case. If the integral is divergent (which I say it is), then various alternatives present themselves; however, `Integrate` does not avail itself of these alternatives, whereas, `FourierTransform` uses one, one that yields the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple code which will do exactly what you wanted:

```
rule = Integrate[Exp[I*t_*x_], {x_, -∞, ∞}] :> 2 Pi DirectDelta[t];
Integrate[Exp[I*(t1-t2)*ω, {ω, -∞, ∞}] /. rule // Quiet
```

The purpose of `Quiet` is to ignore the error message from the `Integrate` which will return an unevaluted `Integrate` expression and then the replacement `rule` is to tell Mathematica we want to give the integral the value we want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple and direct answer. This is just what I need.

Answer (score 9):

It's a Fourier integral. With those, *Mathematica* can confidently venture into generalized function territory and yield things like `DiracDelta` (hazardous in general). However, it doesn't recognize this unless you formulate the integral as a Fourier transform.

```
InverseFourierTransform[1, \[Omega], t, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] /. t -> t1 - t2
(* 2 \[Pi] DiracDelta[t1 - t2] *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But this is not what I need. I hope to yield the DiracDelta from Intagration directly, without considering Fourier transformation. Is it possiple to realize this purpose by defining some rules in Intagration?

Answer (score 3):

it Diverge look at examples here http://courses.washington.edu/ph227814/228/nb/Green.nb.pdf

Thus you must do it by `FourierTransform`

```
k = t1 - t2;

FourierTransform[Exp[I k w], w, 0, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for you kind help. But this is not what I need. I hope to yield the DiracDelta from Intagration directly, without considering Fourier transformation. Is it possiple to realize this purpose by defining some rules in Intagration?