# Integral giving a Dirac delta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, generalized-function

I have the following type of integral

```
Integrate[ r BesselJ[n, a r] BesselJ[n, b r], {r, 0, Infinity}
```

(where `a` and `b` are real and $ n $ are integers) which Mathematica tells me it diverges.

We know that the result is actually

$$
\int_0^{\infty}  J_\mu (a r) J_\mu (b r) \quad r \quad dr = \frac{\delta(a-b)}{a}
$$

The problem is the `Integrate` function is unable to recognize a delta function.
I have tried a few options that were suggested as using `FourierTransform` (which does not work because the expression seems to complicated to Fourier transform it) and also the `TagSetDelayed` option ([Teaching Mathematica more about DiracDelta and KroneckerDelta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110263/teaching-mathematica-more-about-diracdelta-and-kroneckerdelta#new-answer?newreg=344f732162f9423badf3c9911600500d) ).

In any case I did not manage to solve that. Is there any form of doing it?

Comment: The integral doesn't depend on `n`?

Comment: I corrected the expression, there was a mistake.

Comment: @ MarcBorrell Still the righthandside of your equation doesn't depend on `\[Mu]`. Where did you find this formula?

Comment: <https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/02/02/0006/>
It is from here. The result does not depend on mu.

Comment: Here you find a "confirmation" of your formula `Integrate[
   t BesselJ[\[Nu], a t] BesselJ[\[Nu], b t], {t, 0, 
    Infinity}] == (1/a) DiracDelta[a - b] /; 
 Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals] && Element[\[Nu], Reals]`

Comment: Does that come from Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, from   link you gave!

Comment: I see. But, is there  way of making Mathematica "understand" that integral? I mean if you plug in the integral it says that it does not converge.

Comment: Something strange. `Integrate[BesselJ[1, 2*r]*BesselJ[1, 3*r]*r, {r, 0, Infinity}]` says  "Integrate::idiv: Integral of r BesselJ[1,2 r] BesselJ[1,3 r] does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}." and `NIntegrate[BesselJ[1, 2*r]*BesselJ[1, 3*r]*r, {r, 0, Infinity}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
 Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]` performs a warning "NumericalMathNSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect." and `0.096` and the numeric integral over $(0,2000)$ confirms it.

Comment: Gradshtein&Ruezhik includes 6.521.1 with the identical integrand. The result is rather like  the Kronecker delta. I have no time to verify that.

Comment: @user64494  The formula is correct, and it is not the Kronecker delta.

Comment: @yarchik: Can you kindly ground your claim? TIA.

Comment: `Normal[Series[BesselJ[1, 2*r]^2*r, {r, Infinity, 2}]]` results in `(1/\[Pi] + 15/(256 \[Pi] r^2)) Cos[\[Pi]/4 + 2 r]^2 - (
 3 Cos[\[Pi]/4 + 2 r] Sin[\[Pi]/4 + 2 r])/(8 \[Pi] r) + (
 9 Sin[\[Pi]/4 + 2 r]^2)/(256 \[Pi] r^2)` and this implies the diververgence (if I or Mathematica are not mistaken).

Comment: `Normal[Series[r*BesselJ[1, 2*r]*BesselJ[1, 3*r], {r, Infinity, 2}]];Integrate[%, {r, 1, Infinity}]` produces an error communication "Integrate::idiv: Integral of <<1>>/(1536 Sqrt[6] \[Pi] r^2) does not converge on {1,\[Infinity]}.". In view of it the formula under consideration does not seem to be true. Likely a typo.

Comment: @user64494 Why do you think the series can be integrated here? What you are doing is not mathematically rigorous. Moreover, you comments discourage other people (me including) to provide answers!

Comment: @yarchik: See [here](https://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/Russian_sites/Calc1-ru/14/02.htm) (in Russian).

Comment: @user64494 I am sorry, I do not see the connection. According to the [Fubini](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged) theorems, one can exchange series expansion and integration when either left or right hand sides are finite.  But your series expansion contains $1/r^2$, therefore MA is correct in saying that integral of series does not converge. But this makes no implication about the convergence or divergence of the original integral. At least I do not see.

Comment: @yarchik: Up to to the cited link, the integrals of `r*BesselJ[1, 2*r]*BesselJ[1, 3*r]` and `Normal[Series[r*BesselJ[1, 2*r]*BesselJ[1, 3*r], {r, Infinity, 2}]]` converge or diverge simultaneously.

Comment: This integral "almost" converges, insofar as it converges if your factor changes from `r` to `r^(1-epsilon)`. So you can do e.g. `regularizedDelta = 
 Integrate[r^eps1*BesselJ[nu, a*r]*BesselJ[nu, b*r], {r, 0, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> {a > b > 0, nu > 0, 0 < eps1 < 1}]`. A plot will then confirm the delta-like result: `Plot[Re[Evaluate[
   regularizedDelB /. {nu -> 1, a -> 3, eps1 -> .99}]], {b, 2, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`. To be sure it has the correct factor (which I would expect to be `1/(a-b)` if `a>b` by the way), one might numerically integrate against test functions.

Comment: Actually what I wrote might be off in terms of regularization: possibly `a` needs to be less than 0 rather than 1.. It still seems to work...

Comment: @yarchik No need to break integrand into an infinite series and then have to worry about swapping integral with summation. Just split into two (or possibly three) lead terms and all the rest. The "all the rest" part can be shown to converge. The lead term part can be shown to not converge due to oscillatory behavior. Ergo, divergence for the integral in the classical sense.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't succeed in making Mathematica "understand" your integral.

The wellknown simpler case `Integrate[Exp[I \[Omega] t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}] ==  2 Pi DiracDelta[\[Omega]]` isn't understood by Mathematica too:

```
Integrate[Exp[I ω t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}] 
(*Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(I t ω) does not converge on {-∞,∞}.*)
```

But workaround `AsymptoticIntegrate` evaluates to

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[Exp[I ω t], {t, -m, m}, {m, Infinity, 1}] 
(*(2 Sin[m ω])/ω*)
```

which is a limit definition of `DiracDelta[\[Omega]`

Comment: What do you mean by "a limit definition"?

Comment: Something like `DiracDelta[x]=Limit[Sin[x/eps]/(Pi x),eps->0]`(see Wikipedia).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a usual limit, but a limit in the weak topology. See [Wiki, Represetations of the delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) to this end. Mathematica does not deal with such limits.

Comment: @user64494 The limit is wellknown in mathematics, physics, signal theory,... Sorry I' m not interested in refreshing this neverending story concerning `DiracDelta`

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@ does not work), can you give a reference to ground your claim?

Comment: @user64494 the [Wikipedia page on Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional) states that the Fourier transform of $1$ is $\delta(x)$ (in the sense of distributions).

Comment: @Roman: Sorry, but Ulrich Neumann confuses a usual limit with a weak limit.

Comment: @user64494 Sorry I didn't confuse anything! Perhaps my answer is based on a weak limit. But since Dirac introduced the concept, it is well accepted and succesfully applied in many applications!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann:-1. No CAS deals with a weak limit.

Comment: I think this is quite a fine answer (and, apparently, I negated a downvote). It's a nice use of `AsymptoticIntegrate` to generalized functions. And a reminder (to me) that the cardinal sine gives a way to approximate the Dirac delta as an actual function. (I usually think about that in terms of Gaussians. Maybe because my head is bell-shaped...)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for your support. It's difficult for me to get used of "downvoting" as a feedback. By the way a very useful limit for Dirac Delta is gaussian ;-) : `dirac[x]~ Limit[ Exp[-(x/eps)^2]/(eps Sqrt[Pi]),eps->0]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:I prefer formulas and references over emotional words.

Comment: @user64494 No mystery intended. What I alluded to is a well known regularization used to compute/approximate generalized functions. Multiply integrand by `Exp[-a*x^2]`, integrate under assumption that `a>0`, take limit as `a->0`. Check `In[5]:= regularizedFT = 
 Integrate[Exp[-a*x^2]*Exp[I*w*x]*Cos[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, Element[w, Reals]}]

Out[5]= (E^(-((1 + w)^2/(4 a))) (1 + E^(w/a)) Sqrt[\[Pi]])/(2 Sqrt[a])` and then do for example `Plot[Abs[regularizedFT /. a -> .01], {w, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]` to see it approximate the FT of the cosine function.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround and under certain assumptions we have:

```
func= r*BesselJ[n, a r]*BesselJ[n, b r];

InverseMellinTransform[Integrate[MellinTransform[func, a, s], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {s > 1, b > 0, n \[Element] Integers, n >= 0, 2 + n > s}], s, a]

(*DiracDelta[a - b]/b*)
```

**[Maple 2020.2](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/academic/)** Can deal:

[image]

Comment: @MariushIwaniuk:  However, the calculations  in Mathematica (see my comments to the question) show that the integral `Integrate[BesselJ[1, 2*r]*BesselJ[1, 3*r]*r, {r, 0, Infinity}]` diverges.

Comment: @user64494 .In this book: https://www.elsevier.com/books/table-of-integrals-series-and-products/zwillinger/978-0-12-384933-5 on page:`669` example:`8` answer is with `Dirac Delta`.

Comment: **PS**: Using: `HankelTransform[BesselJ[n, a*r], r, b, n]`  :)

Comment: @MariushIwaniuk: Can you indicate a number (e.g. 6.643.8 )since I don't find it in the seventh edition?

Comment: @user64494: `6.513.8`.

Comment: @MariushIwanyuk: The handbook refers to Jackson, J. D., Classical Electrodynamics, Wiley, New York, 1975. I will have no time to see that during several hours.

Comment: @MariushEwaniuk: I found [that formula](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f01y4a19muf5hos/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202020-12-04%2021.19.36.png?dl=0), but did not find its derivation in the book.